# How to wrap a specific element in a div

Tags: javascript, html

Currently, my website has the following structure:

```
<div class="aa">

  <h2 class="bb">example</h2>

</div>
```

And I want to create a new div and put h2 inside it.

```
<div class="aa">

    <div class="cc">  <---

          <h2 class="bb">example</h2>

    </div>  <---

</div>
```

I tried using insertBefore code as below.

```
<script>
    const parent = document.querySelector('.bb');
    const billingField1 = document.querySelector('.aa');

    const newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    newDiv.setAttribute('id', 'cc');
    newDiv.style.cssText = 'Hi there';

    parent.insertBefore(newDiv, billingField1);
</script>
```

With this method, a new div element is inserted only with

```
<div class="cc"></div>
```

I'm wondering if there is any way to put it in.

Comment: user [Inner Html](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp)
` const newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    newDiv.setAttribute('id', 'cc');
    newDiv.innerHtml = 'Hi there';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you insert the new element, you need to make the old element a child of it.

```js
const parent = document.querySelector('.aa');
const billingField1 = document.querySelector('.bb');

const newDiv = document.createElement('div');
newDiv.setAttribute('id', 'cc');
newDiv.style.cssText = 'Hi there';

parent.insertBefore(newDiv, billingField1);
newDiv.appendChild(billingField1);
```

```html
<div class="aa">
  <h2 class="bb">example</h2>
</div>
```

You also had the selectors for `parent` and `billingField1` swapped.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
document.getElementByClassName(‘bb’).innerHTML = ‘<div class=“cc”>’ + document.getElementByClassName(‘bb’).innerHTML + ‘</div>’;
```